# Multiple var values in same page

Tags: javascript

I am looking to display two different values from the same variable on the same page.
In one div it should display the value for ID 271 and in another line the value for ID 261.

Is it possible to keep the first value and display another one for the second div?

```js
$('#temp')[0].setAttribute('data-cmd_id', temperature);

jeedom.cmd.update[temperature] = function(_options) {
  jeedom.cmd.execute({ // Récupération de la valeur  
    id: temperature,
    success: function(valeur_courante) {
      // alert(valeur_courante);
      $('.temperature').empty();
      if (valeur_courante == 0) {
        $('.temperature,.iconCmdMouv').css('color', '');
      } else {
        $('.temperature,.iconCmdMouv').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
        $('.temperature').append(valeur_courante);
      }
    }
  })
};
jeedom.cmd.update[temperature]();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var temperature = 271;
  </script>
  <script src="montheme/temperature.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>

  <div id="temp" class="cmd"><span class="iconCmdMouv">
     <i style=""class="fa fa-thermometer-half fa-2x"></i></span>
    <span class="temperature"></span>°C
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var temperature = 261;
    </script>
    <script src="montheme/temperature.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <div id="temp" class="cmd"><span class="iconCmdMouv">
     <i style=""class="fa fa-thermometer-half fa-2x"></i></span>
      <span class="temperature"></span>°C
    </div>
```

I'm sure this is a very basic/stupid question but I don't know much about JS :)

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: IDs should be unique, you can't use `id="temp"`  in multiple DIVs.

Comment: Ok, first mistake :) Then how can I dynamically change the id in my first JS line '('#temp')[0].setAttribute('data-cmd_id', temperature);' ?

Comment: A better method would to write a function that takes an ID and a temperature. Then you can call `set_temp("temp1", 261)` in each `<script>` block.

Comment: your question doesn't make much sense to me. why would you want to have 2 different values for the same variable? why wouldn't you just have 2 variables?

Comment: I would like to use only one JS code and only change variables in the HTML. But yeah I’m sure I’m doing something wrong. Thanks Barmar I will try the function method.

Comment: @Barmar would you be able to help with a bit of code please? I understand the logic but I am not able to write the function from scratch... Thanks

Comment: not now, I'm busy with my real work.

Comment: Haha sure, good luck

Comment: Hi, someone can help me with this function please? I’m sure this is a good solution but don’t really know where to start. Also open to other ideas. Thanks